# Указатель на функцию

Tags: c++

не могу придумать как сделать указатель на начало списка.

```
list <string> listok;
 void Print_edition::show_pe()
{   

    copy(listok.begin(), listok.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
}
```

Необходимо сделать указатель на listok.begin();

**Кто нибудь может подскажет идею?**

Comment: Непонятно, зачем это может понадобиться в таком примере, но `::std::addressof(::std::list<::std::string>::begin)`

Comment: а при чем тут указатель на функцию? begin() - это функция возвращающая итератор на начало списка, вам надо указатель на итератор или указатель на функцию бегин?

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю, вы не смогли нормально сформулировать и вам нужен указатель на первый элемент в списке? Ну так

```
&listok.front()
```

но зачем? Просто ссылки `listok.front()` недостаточно?

Если не это - то сформулируйте вопрос точно и однозначно.

Comment: да нужен , указатель на первый  элемент в списке. Спасибо!

Comment: Ну, если я угадал :) и ответ устроил - то слева от него есть птичка, если на ней щелкнуть - она зеленеет... Проверьте! :)

Comment: такой вопросик еще, а как потом этот указатель применить в copy(ptr1, listok.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));

Comment: А **ЗАЧЕМ??** Туда передается итератор, указывающий на начало списка - все, как у вас изначально и написано: `copy(listok.begin(), listok.end(), .....`